# about permission to access “Caches” work on iOS 14 but iOS15 fail

Tags: ios14, ios15

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“-8985631368586039364” couldn’t be moved because you don’t have permission to access “Caches”." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-1924357422564807023/-8985631368586039364, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Move
), NSDestinationFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1DBCCEA5-71CD-470A-A315-4F5AD23AB361/Library/Caches/bgdl-3364-e54b4f1eaf236e91.xzip, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-1924357422564807023/-8985631368586039364, NSUnderlyingError=0x280f14c30 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

my app will download file and save. it work on iOS14, but iOS15.

i can not catch any usefull exection when downloading fail(actually download finish, not call finish methos) .

I have no idea . Please help.

Comment: it work on simulate device iOS15, but real device fail

Comment: i found that using NewsstandKit with NKAssetDownload

Comment: I'm also having this issue.. figure something out?

Comment: Please see it https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691289. NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate is replaced with NSURLSessionDownloadTask. I found NKAssetDownload method is "(NSURLConnection *)downloadWithDelegate:(id <NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate>)delegate;". May be not work on iOS15.